# Android ViewPager Direction

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have problem with viewpager widget.my application have four tab when i run my application viewpager start from tab four but i want start from tab one.how could change direction of viewpager?is there any thirty-party library?
[image]

Comment: try yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "change the direction"? It'll still be swiping left to go left and right to go right. If you want to have it open to the last tab on launch, then in your `onCreate()` method, add this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(sacedInstanceState);

    . . . 

    ViewPager viewPager = . . .; //initialize however you want here
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
}
```